# How do i display different fxml files on a stage for scene builder? Switching scene?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, scene

There are other tutorials on such, but they are not in a very **basic** manner. Most of them have other aspects which makes beginners like myself harder to understand...

How do I switch scene or FXML files on a stage by use of a button?

**Main.Java Class**

```js
package application;
 

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen 1.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

**Controller.java Class**

```js
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Controller {

 public void goToScreen2(){
  System.out.println("Going to screen2");
  
  
  
 } 
 
 public void goToScreen1(){
  System.out.println("Going to screen1");
  


  
  
 } 
}
```

**Screen 1 fxml file**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="203.0" layoutY="132.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToScreen2" text="Go to screen 2" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**Screen 2 fxml file**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="248.0" layoutY="116.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToScreen1" text="Go to screen 1" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store controllers in the application, and show associated components as needed.

**Main.Java Class**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public Controller controller1;
    public Controller controller2;
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        controller1 = load("Screen 1.fxml");
        controller2 = load("Screen 2.fxml");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        controller1.goToScreen1();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Controller load(final String name) throws IOException {
        final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(name));
        loader.load();
        final Controller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.configure(this, new Scene(loader.getRoot()));
        return controller;
    }

    public void show(final Scene scene) {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java Class**

```
public class Controller {
    private Main application;
    private Scene scene;

    public void configure(final Main application, final Scene scene) {
        this.application = application;
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public void show() {
        application.show(scene);
    }

    public void goToScreen2() {
        application.controller2.show();
    }

    public void goToScreen1() {
        application.controller1.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.Main.load(Main.java:36)
 at application.Main.start(Main.java:25)

Comment: this "   controller.configure(this, loader.getRoot())"

Comment: I've forget to call `loader.load();` before trying to get the controller. Plus, other code simplified a little bit.

Comment: Thank you works great!  Since I have all the "pages" loaded will this decrease the performance of such program?

Comment: It is possible to load pages on demand, but I don't think that performance will be an issue.

Comment: what if i wanted to have multiple controllers? to initialize things for each page say a choicebox that lists an arraylist of items?